# Как в bash'е найти и удалить файлы

Tags: linux, регулярные-выражения, bash

Как в bash'е найти все файлы в папке (рекурсивно) с именем вида `*(n)*`, где n - именно число в скобках, и кроме чисел ничего нет,
 и удалить их?

Comment: Вам совсем чуть-чуть поменять ваш regex... Только наверное лучше указать какие регулярки используются в вашей ОС, т.к. у меня тест в Centos7 вполне корректно отрабатывает и захватывает и в т.ч. и filename (2) - man find говорит, что "-regextype type Changes the regular expression syntax understood by  -regex  and -iregex tests which occur later on the command line.  Currently implemented types are emacs (this is  the  default),  posix-awk,      posix-basic, posix-egrep and posix-extended."

Comment: Как оказалось, у меня тоже все корректно отрабатывает.

Answer (score 6):

работает. проверено на Ubuntu (14.04)

```
find . -regextype sed -xtype f -regex ".*([0-9]*).*" -delete
```

Comment: А самый тривиальный `find . -name '*([0-9]*)*' -delete` не работает?

Comment: не совсем, в выборку попадают файлы не только с цифровым постфиксом, например: `filename (abc).txt`

Comment: Так они и в ваш тоже попадут

Comment: Нет, не попадают. Проверьте. `finename (nabc).txt` где n-число

Comment: Да, в самом деле. Это шелл регэксп, сопоставляется с цифрой и чем угодно после нее.

Comment: Теперь ваши вопрос-ответ смотрятся хорошо. Я бы еще акцентировал в вопросе внимание к тому, что кроме цифр ничего другого в скобках не должно быть.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте также

```
find . -type f -name "[0-9]" -exec rm -f {} \;
```

Comment: А как же условие про скобки?